# Cannot search for packages to install using muon or synaptic

Tags: kubuntu, synaptic, muon-package-manager

I installed Kubuntu 14.04 fresh. The package list is up to date.

The problem is I cannot search for packages to install using muon or synaptic.
The package is there in the list of packages. But when I search for it, both package managers show nothing.

[image: Searching for Php5 package gives no result]

[image: But when I scroll down.. the package is present]

Answer (score 2):

This may have been a problem with both the package managers not indexing the packages for searching.

I did a few reloads from synaptic package manager and it solved the problem.